# Is it possible to build (configure) the recurly js form multiple times?

Tags: javascript, recurly

After calling `recurly.configure()` to build my billing form the first time, I am no longer able to create the form again if I navigate away and come back. The embedded iframe inputs do not show up.

The site I'm working on is a single page application so the recurly js library (v4) is only ever loaded once. Is there any way to make sure the form can be built every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known behavior with Recurly.js v4 at this time. Recurly is working on an enhancement to permit the rebuilding of the form and reset the fields without need of a page refresh.

This topic has an ongoing discussion at https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js/issues/239, feel free to join in there to get updates on progress.